# Eclipse target definition is empty

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, target-platform

For some mysterious reason all the target definition files (*.target) in my plugin project became empty.

I have absolutely no clue how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

With the information provided in the question it is difficult to guess the reason.

However you can try these

1. Open target file in **Text Editor** and check the content.If the size of the file is more than zero then you can see some content here.
2. If using any SCM tool get the older version of these files.
3. You can replace the file content in local history. Right click on the file go to `Replace with > Local History` then choose the older one and click Replace.

Comment: I opened the target definition file with a text editor and it showed me some content. Could it be that my eclipse version can't handle the target def file ?

Comment: post the target file content